# 06 Toyota Avalon Sensor positions

Tags: cel, camshaft, crankshaft, avalon

Looking for help diagnoising a couple issues with my Avalon. I have some codes coming up, bad crankshaft sensor and bad camshaft sensor. I also have the cel, vsc, and trac light on. I tried replacing with gas cap and clearing the codes with no luck. So I'm gonna try and replace these sensors and go from there however I cant find any diagram online for my specific make and model to find there locations in the engine. No owners manual. Anyone have any pictures to help?

Comment: There are 4 cam sensors they should be mounted on the front of the heads or to the sides the crank sensor is mounted in the front cover. What are the codes?

Comment: I'll have to check again, but 2 saying emissions leaks (large and small) some misfiring, then a code each for camshaft and crankshaft. I'll check again later today for the exact codes.